# mod_rewrite regexp with parameters

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite, apache2

Trying to create a php file that dynamically resizes an image for web on demand.

I have the php working, now i want "pretty" URLs for it, currently i have this

```
RewriteRule ^/gallery/images/([0-9a-zA-Z._]+)?$ /gallery/image.php?path=$1
```

which pretty much works

what I am after though is a way of passing in the path of the image when its not just sitting within "gallery" (think albums and sub albums)

so would like to be able to go to the following url

```
[TLD]/gallery/[album]/[[sub-album]]/[image]
```

so

```
$1 = [album]/[[sub-album]]/[image]
```

is this possible? if so, how?

EDIT:
wasn't clear enough originally, sub gallery, can be none, or many (unknown number) and the rewrite should be able to handle this.

Comment: I don't mean to be off-topic, but I just want to say that it is my opinion that it's way batter to have everything sent to a php script and to parse the url in the applcation as it gives you more flexibility, it is easier to make changes and you don't depend this much on the server (what happens if you switch to nginx and you don't have mod_rewrite)

Comment: i wont! i promise you! this runs on a simple linux box in my living room - i have 100% full control over this, it is just for my personal website, plus i like apache :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/gallery/([^/]+/[^/]+/[0-9a-zA-Z._]+)$ /gallery/image.php?path=$1
```

You can edit pattern of the [image], I substituted this `[0-9a-zA-Z._]+`.

Comment: that assumes, there is always a sub gallery, which isnt always true, hence the double square brackets (sorry wasnt very clear - will go back an edit) sub galleries can be none, or many